# Compare Array elements and add based on key and value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays like this:

```
$array_1 = Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 6 [2] => 2 [3] => 6 [4] => 4 [5] => 10 [6] => 4 [7] => 6 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 4 [11] => 4 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 );

$array_2 = Array ( [0] => DK [1] => GA [2] => DK [3] => GA [4] => DK [5] => GA [6] => WE [7] => VE [8] => WE [9] => VE [10] => PLA [11] => PRA [12] => PLA [13] => PRA ) ;
```

Now I want result like this:

```
$dk=4+2+4=10;
$ga=6+6+10=22;
$we=4+2=6;
$ve=6+2=8;
$pla=4+2=6;
$pra=4+2;
```

Explanation:

In `$array_2`, `'DK'` exists 3 times and `key values are = 0,2 and 4.`
    So, i have to add the values of `$array_1` having `key 0,2,4` and assign them to `$dk`. Here, `$dk` will be `4+2+4=10`. This process will be same for all other variables.
        How can i do this??

Comment: You can do it with your keyboard.

Comment: you need all in different variables? why?

Comment: yes, it is needed to assign each result to separate variables. Note that, variables name is not dynamic. It will be created manually.

Comment: Then you should definitely re-think your data structure.  This is not professional-grade.   Consider a multi-dimensional array with keys from the unique values in `$array_2` and subarrays containing the relative data from `$array_1`.  When you have grouped the numbers into their groups, you can just all `array_sum()` on them and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead separate variable name I suggest you to make array like this

```
<?php
$array_1 = [4,6,2,6];
$array_2 = [ 0=> "DK", 1=>"GA", 2=>"DK", 3=>"GA"];
$newArray = [];
foreach($array_2 as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($newArray[$value])){
    $newArray[$value] +=$array_1[$key];
  }else{
    $newArray[$value] =$array_1[$key];
  }
}
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1004998)

Output :

```
Array
(
    [DK] => 6
    [GA] => 12
)
```

**Another suggestion** : Instead complex programming try to make good relation or binding to not get any inconsistency in records

Answer (score 1):

This will loop array2 and build an array with the sum.
Then output it (just to see the result), then I use extract to pull out the variables as you want them.
*But I would rather keep them in the array*

```
Foreach($array_2 as $key => $val){
    If(!isset($new[$val])) $new[$val] =0;
    $new[$val] += $array_1[$key];
}
Var_dump($new);
Extract($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/jOR7Z